# Error con PHP "Notice: Undefined index:" y no conecta con DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Buenas estoy probando guardar comentarios en BD pero me devuelve el error que sale en el titulo de esta pregunta.

tengo el siguiente FORM en un index.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" action="guarda_comentario.php" method="post">
        <input name="txtalias" value=""/>
        <textarea name="txtcomentario" value=""></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

y el siguiente php que es el `action` del form anterior.

```
include 'conectar.php';  

$varalias = $_POST['txtalias']; 
$varcomentario = $_POST['txtcomentario'];   

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla_comentarios (alias, comentario) VALUES ('$varalias', '$varcomentario')"; 

$result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); 
if (!$result){ 
    echo "ERROR: No se pudo guardar la informacion, contacte al administrador."; 
}else{ 
    echo "<b>Información guardada correctamente.</b>"; 
}
```

Ya he probado cambiar las variables en las que recibo los valores por POST A:

`$varalias = isset($_POST['txtalias']) ? $_POST['txtalias'] : '';
 $varcomentario = isset($_POST['txtcomentario']) ? $_POST['txtcomentario'] : '';`

Esto hace que deje de enviarme el error  "Notice: Undefined index:"
en su defecto me devuelve la linea de error que yo mismo he codificado y contemplado:

`echo "ERROR: No se pudo guardar la informacion, contacte al administrador.";`

la cual no puedo dilucidar porque no esta guardando los valores en BBDD. el archivo `contectar.php` a continuación.

```
<?php

$user='root';
$pass='';
$server='localhost';

$mysqli = new mysqli($server,$user,$pass)  or die ( "no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" ); 

echo "conectado correctamente";
```

?>

como verán , muy simple. Pero si vemos el error que me devuelve por pantalla es

"conectado correctamenteERROR: No se pudo guardar la informacion, contacte al administrador."

lo primero que sale es "Conectado correctamente" esto es el `echo` del archivo `conectar.php` lo cual este archivo esta funcionando correctamente.

por lo tanto ¿Porque no captura los valores del form en index.html?¿Porqe no los guarda en BBDD?

Aguardo sus comentarios.

Saludos

Comment: Si califican negativo por lo menos dejar un comentario de ¿porque? ¿no?, de esta manera se edita la pregunta.

Comment: tu conexión esta incompleta, en ningún lado estás escribiendo el nombre de la BD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta el nombre de la base de datos en tu archivo de conexión.

```
<?php
  $user='root';
  $pass='';
  $server='localhost';
  $basedatos= 'nombre_de_tu_base_de_datos';

  $mysqli = new mysqli($server,$user,$pass, $basedatos)  or die ( "no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" ); 

  echo "conectado correctamente";
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: Es correcto muchas gracias, error de novato.

Comment: Tranquilo, a muchos nos pasa!!!